# Sharepoint 2013 device channels

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, device-channel

I am experiencing wired issue, I have configured device channels and added some user agent strings related to it. When I access site externally on an iPad, no issues occur, but when I access the same thing using an iPhone, it gives me a login prompt.

If anyone knows what is the cause of issue, please let know.

Answer (score 1):

Check if all the resources associated with the iPhone device channel are checked in and published as a major version.

Answer (score 0):

This links helped me if any one intrested.

[http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff393836(v=office.15).aspx](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff393836%28v=office.15%29.aspx)

Comment: Please add more details to this answer

Answer (score 0):

the reason could be that the master page or the resources associated with the iphone based device channel is getting challenged with authentication.

try to revisit the setting as see.

Answer (score 0):

The issue was for some reason css ref form IIS folder asking authentication. Changed ref from IIS to sharepoint gallery.